# Include playlist id in output when getting a list of user's playlist tracks in Spotify

Tags: python, spotify

My objective is to create a CSV of all the songs I've added in my playlists, while indicating which playlist the song was added to.

I have a list of playlist IDs that I'm looping through in Python as I'm making the requests through 
`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks`. The fields I'm interested are:

```
items(added_by.id, added_at,track(name,id,duration_ms,album(name,id), artists(name, id)))
```

My current output is as follows (displaying one track only):

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "added_at" : "2017-02-28T16:58:10Z",
    "added_by" : {
      "id" : "nelsonology"
    },
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "id" : "2UhSfdDHLBBbWK4ifose0x",
        "name" : "Love Slacker"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "id" : "5BhFZpE8kUGZJiKOsYjLQM",
        "name" : "Yeek"
      } ],
      "duration_ms" : 245577,
      "id" : "6z3fmpMqgV3a8DYZgdiU7w",
      "name" : "I'm Not Ready"
    }
  }
 }
```

So my question is if there is a way (and if so, how) to either:

1. Add the playlist id into the JSON output
2. Add the playlist id into the CSV output

I'm not familiar with APIs or Python so any guidance on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call the `/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks`, you already have the playlist id. In order to convert that playlist to a csv, you could write something like:

```py
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

scope = 'user-library-read'
# Define the playlist id out here so we can use it later
userid = '11995522'
playlistid = 'testplaylistid'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.user_playlist_tracks(userid, playlistid, 'items(added_by.id, added_at,track(name,id,duration_ms,album(name,id), artists(name, id)))')
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print ','.join([
            # This inserts the playlist ID into your CSV output
            playlistid,
            item['added_by']['id'],
            item['added_at'],
            item['track']['name'],
            item['track']['id'],
            item['track']['duration_ms'],
            item['track']['album']['name'],
            item['track']['album']['id'],
            item['track']['artists'][0]['name'],
            item['track']['artists'][0]['id'],
          ])
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

This example uses the [spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python Spotify API Wrapper library. Documentation for that is available online.

Hope that helps!